# Copied Better_Combat.dzip into CookedPC, but no effect

Tags: the-witcher-2

As described on the [Help page](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/44/?), the .dzip should be copied into CookedPC. I did that, but the Quen Sign still has a duration of 30s when I load my savegame. Any way to check if the mod das been loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if the mod is downloaded correctly is to download the tooltips of the same mod.

[Link Here](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/download/514)

On the about page it is highly recommended that you do this anyway so that you can see the full effects of the mod. This secondary mod is described below.

**Better Combat - Tooltips**

> These are the altered in-game descriptions in english, russian, italian, french and polish. To install extract the version you want depending on the language on the CookedPC folder.

This will allow you to see if the changes have taken effect. I have checked and if the main mod was not installed correctly then no changes will appear with the tooltips.

In conclusion, install this and you will be able to see if the core mod has installed correctly.

Comment: Hm. The quen sign still has a 30s duration and now the game goes black if I go to the character screen.

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling it completely then, something has gone wrong during the process